# Does AWS EC2 Auto-Scaling add new instance exactly like current one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

When EC2 auto-scaling group adds a new instance, is it adding one exactly like the current instance (assuming you only have one as a baseline) including any changes you have made post launch, or does it start one that is identical to the first instance's initial state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will launch whatever AMI was specified in the Launch Configuration. All instances launched by the ASG launch configuration will be identical to the state defined by the AMI.

See 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html